# Why my bitmap image have another color overlay after converting 32-bit to 8-bit

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp

Im working on resizing bitmap image and converting bitmap image to 8-bit (grayscale). But I have the problem that when I convert 32-bit image to 8-bit image, the result has another color overlay while it works perfectly on 24-bit. I guess the cause is in the alpha color. but I dont know where the problem exactly is.

This is my code to generate 8-bit palette color and write it after **DIB** part:

```
char* palette = new char[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    palette[i * 4] = palette[i * 4 + 1] = palette[i * 4 + 2] = (char)i;
    palette[i * 4 + 3] = 255;
}
fout.write(palette, 1024);
delete[] palette;
```

As I said, my code works perfectly on 24-bit. In 32-bit the color is still kept after resizing, but when converting to 8-bit, it will look like this:
[expected image (when converted from 24-bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yadRt.jpg) //
[unexpected image (when converted from 32-bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjEfE.png)

This is how I get the colors and save it to `srcPixel[]`:

```
int i = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int index = getIndex(width, x, y);
        srcPixel[index].A = srcBMP.pImageData[i];
        i += alpha;
        srcPixel[index].B = srcBMP.pImageData[i++];
        srcPixel[index].G = srcBMP.pImageData[i++];
        srcPixel[index].R = srcBMP.pImageData[i++];
    }
    i += padding;
}
```

And this is the code I converted it by getting average of 4 colors A, B, G and R from that `srcPixel[]`:

```
int i = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < dstHeight; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < dstWidth; x++) {
        int index = getIndex(dstWidth, x, y);
        dstBMP.pImageData[i++] = (srcPixel[index].A + srcPixel[index].B + srcPixel[index].G + srcPixel[index].R) / 4;
    }
    i += dstPadding;
}
```

---

If I remove and skip all alpha bytes in my code, when converting my image is still like that and I will have another problem is when resizing, my image will have another color overlay like the problem when converting to 8-bit: [resizing without alpha channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Qly.jpg).

If I skip the alpha channel while getting average (change into `dstBMP.pImageData[i++] = (srcPixel[index].B + srcPixel[index].G + srcPixel[index].R) / 3`, there is **almost** nothing different, the overlay still exists.

If I remove `palette[i * 4 + 3] = 255;` or doing anything with it, the result is still not affected.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what's `dstBMP.pImageData`?

Comment: @tansy it is the image data (which saves color bytes) in destination image.

Comment: So you add alpha channel to your color. Check the answer and say if it's right or not.

Answer (score 0):

You add alpha channel to the color and that's why it becomes brighter. From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/alpha-blending) I found that opaque is 255 and transparent 0 - therefore you add another channel which is set to 'white' to your result.

Remove alpha channel from your equation and see if I'm right.

Comment: how can I fix it? because if I delete and skip all alpha color in my code, I will have another problem is that it will have another color overlay when resizing, and if I ignore the alpha color only when getting average (I mean `(srcPixel[index].B + srcPixel[index].G + srcPixel[index].R) / 3`), there is nothing different, the grayscale image still same (have another color overlay exactly like that).

Comment: I have answered your question, that's 1. And 2, I don't really understand your objections. Your "new" should not be new, it should be old, exactly (apart from necessary conversion to 8 bit) like old and alpha is alpha. In 8-bit-colour image it's at most 1 bit. So you have to convert colour to colour and alpha to alpha. Not mix it up. Obviously, as name states, colour is colour and alpha is alpha.

Comment: Im sorry, because I took it from different functions, I will edit it. and about "alpha to alpha", how I can do it? thank you very much..

Comment: In the image you uset there is "no alpha", it's opaque (255) and if you have such images and want to preserve it then you will have to "round it" form 8-bit to 1-bit.

Comment: can you post an answer for me? Im really sorry for my stupid, but I still dont get your idea, Im really sorry

Comment: Alpha channel may be misleading name. It's another channel of information and this information is alpha, or, in case of bitmap opacity. A=0 means 0 opacity == transparency, and 255 full opacity == !transparency, and between, proportionally to the value. In 8-bit with transparency, it's actually 7-bit colour and 1 bit of alpha (opacity), sou would need to round range [0, 255] => [0, 1], for example `if(Alpha_8_bit>127) Alpha_1_bit = 1;`.

Comment: BTW, it this answers your question, it would be a good manners to accept the answer.

Comment: maybe you misunderstood my question

Comment: Simple question - did excluding alpha channel from your colour conversion work?

Comment: I added all in the end of my question

Comment: Your colour convertion for 32-bit should be same as from 24bit. Alpha is not a colour.
Alpha is alpha. and is separate information. If it works for you from 24bit to 8bit then it will work for 32bit to 8bit.